# Can I configure Google to favour fresh publications and/or use particular time frame by default?

Tags: google-search

I have found myself clicking Search tools - Past year / Past month too often, in the majority of the cases when I search I am looking for fresh publications as information gets obsolete quickly in my area of interest. So, I would like to see new posts first usually. Can I pre-configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Doesn't appear to be an option in preferences](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2539428?hl=en).

You can bookmark this URL to search the past month

`https://www.google.com/webhp?tbs=qdr:m`

You can bookmark this URL to search the past year

`https://www.google.com/webhp?tbs=qdr:y`